# Is it possible to change the font of the text from a listing?

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I have a listing of my Java code currently the font is too big and the code runs off the page.

Here is what my listing looks like:

[image]

Comment: To reduce the length of the code you can use the `lstset` options `columns=fullflexible` and `basicstyle=\small` or even `basicstyle=\scriptsize`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change `basicstyle` and `linewidth` to achieve what you want. I, for example, use the following within my lstlistings-settings:

```
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
linewidth=\textwidth
```

Additionally, I import the courier package to get a nicer font for `ttfamily`using `\usepackage{courier}`

EDIT: I also use Java code within LaTeX documents quite regularly. This is how my total setup looks like:

```
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    linewidth=\textwidth,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\emptyaccsupp,
    columns=flexible,
    numbersep=5pt,      % Abstand der Nummern zum Text
    tabsize=3,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf,
    commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
    frame=bottomline,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry}\ttfamily,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
    framexrightmargin=5pt,
    framexbottommargin=4pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    literate=%
        {Ö}{{\"O}}1
        {Ä}{{\"A}}1
        {Ü}{{\"U}}1
        {ß}{{\ss}}2
        {ü}{{\"u}}1
        {ä}{{\"a}}1
        {ö}{{\"o}}1
 }
 \lstloadlanguages{
         Java
 }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to directly modify the font size?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus You can use anything from `\tiny` to `\Huge` as a setting for `basicstyle`. Just the usual LaTeX way of setting the font size

Comment: What about automatic page breaks?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Here is an example of Processing using the style I posted in my answer: [Screenshot example](http://i.imgur.com/kFnu8.png)

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus please have a look at the [listings package manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf)!